# Paginate Count Query in Cakephp 3.0 slow

Tags: mysql, performance, cakephp, count, pagination

I have a problem with the `count()` of paginate still in *cakephp version 3.3*:

My table has 6,000,000 records.
The fields involved here are `name` and `cityf`. Both have index in MySQL

I'm showing 10 and 10 and despite the query is very fast, the `count()` of paginate is taking more than 50 seconds.

How to solve this in version 3.3 of cakephp. Follows the two SQL statements and times below:

Select query main:

```
SELECT 
  Rr.id AS `Rr__id`, 
  Rr.idn AS `Rr__idn`, 
  Rr.aniver AS `Rr__aniver`, 
  Rr.pessoa AS `Rr__pessoa`, 
  Rr.name AS `Rr__name`, 
  Rr.phoner AS `Rr__phoner`, 
  Rr.tipolf AS `Rr__tipolf`, 
  Rr.addressf AS `Rr__addressf`, 
  Rr.num_endf AS `Rr__num_endf`, 
  Rr.complem AS `Rr__complem`, 
  Rr.bairrof AS `Rr__bairrof`, 
  Rr.cityf AS `Rr__cityf`, 
  Rr.statef AS `Rr__statef`, 
  Rr.cepf AS `Rr__cepf`, 
  Rr.n1 AS `Rr__n1`, 
  Rr.n2 AS `Rr__n2`, 
  Rr.smerc AS `Rr__smerc`, 
  Rr.n3 AS `Rr__n3`, 
  Rr.n4 AS `Rr__n4`, 
  Rr.fone AS `Rr__fone`, 
  Rr.numero AS `Rr__numero` 
FROM 
  `MG` Rr 
WHERE 
  (
    Rr.name like 'MARCOS%' 
    AND Rr.cityf like 'BELO HORIZONTE%'
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  name asc 
LIMIT 
  10 OFFSET 0
```

= 10 ms

Explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  Rr  range   NAME,CITYF,cityfbairrof,cityfaddressf,cityfbairrofaddressf,namen1n2n3n4     NAME    63  NULL    21345   Using index condition; Using where
```

-
Select query count:

```
SELECT 
  (
    COUNT(*)
  ) AS `count` 
FROM 
  `MG` Rr 
WHERE 
  (
    Rr.name like 'MARCOS%' 
    AND Rr.cityf like 'BELO HORIZONTE%'
  )
```

= 51.247 ms

Explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  Rr  range   NAME,CITYF,cityfbairrof,cityfaddressf,cityfbairrofaddressf,namen1n2n3n4     NAME    63  NULL    21345   Using index condition; Using where
```

---

It's happening in several other cases: Always count of query is very slow.

I appreciate any help.

Marcos

Comment: More information: If i put only field name for example, the count query is fast too, but if add other (field cityf) the count query is very slow).

Comment: in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574466/how-can-you-remove-or-change-the-cakephp-pagination-count-query-on-postgresql have one solution for bypass  the pagination count, but it not work in version 3.0 cakephp... I realy need use paginate and if could bypass count and show only next button is one solution. How to do this in version 3.3 of cakephp?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130780/mysql-count-performance . It discusses the performance issue with MySQL and COUNT()

Comment: What was the count?